# How do you change a TTF font name?

Tags: windows, fonts, rename, truetype-fonts, truetype

How can I change a font name (not the ttf filename, but the actual font name)?

For example, I want to rename "Tahoma" to "Tahoma7".

My goal is to rename the Tahoma font installed on Windows 7 and install it on Windows XP under different name, so I will have both Tahoma fonts installed on a single operating system. The two fonts are slightly different, and I'd like to have them both.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[FontForge](https://fontforge.org) may be of use:

> **FontForge** -- An outline font editor
>   that lets you create your own
>   postscript, truetype, opentype,
>   cid-keyed, multi-master, cff, svg and
>   bitmap (bdf, FON, NFNT) fonts, or edit
>   existing ones. Also lets you convert
>   one format to another. FontForge has
>   support for many macintosh font
>   formats.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. I have used other free font editor Type 2.2, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Using Win7 SP1 it keeps crashing on me.  It also couldn't navigate to a different drive other than C: and didn't have an intuitive save as type setup.

Comment: @VoteCoffee You can type <driveletter>: in the open dialog and press enter, this opens up the open dialog of a different drive. (Not too intuitive, I just found it accidentally and it seemed useful to share)

Comment: Free / Open Source!

Answer (score 15):

TTX is a command line tool and can be make it pretty simple to change a font's name.  There's a tutorial on how to do exactly that here:  http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=343

[Download TTX as part of fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)

Comment: The project has been removed.

Comment: @Gruber it can be found here: https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools

Comment: Is it legal to change the name of the font?

Comment: Tutorial link is dead

Comment: [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506213431/http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=343)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Typograf](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/) for that.

Navigate to the folder where font is located, select .ttf file, click Properties. Properties window will appear:

[image]

Change font names (font family, full name, Postscript name etc) as required and click "Save as..." button.

Comment: works nicely - and quick install

Comment: Horrible, terrible UI, and the buttons move to try and trick you into buying it

Comment: -1 This shareware isn't worth the money

Comment: The close dialog box is too much annoying

Comment: Who cares about the UI when this gets the job done (and it got updated in the meantime). Out of all suggested solutions, THIS did the job. Even when it's shareware, it let me do it without having to pay. It edited the meta data only, without modifying the font itself. FontForge and others tampered with the font data, which lead to serious problems. Look at this answer for additional information why this is important to be aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876695/4348149

Comment: The version I just downloaded no longer seems to have the ability to click on the above fields to edit them.

Answer (score 4):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427523/1107290) on StackOverflow:

> - Import your font file in the online [Glyphrstudio font editor](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/)
> - Click the hamburger icon on the top left
> - Select **font setting** and change title and meta data from there

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/windows-dl/).
2. Right-click and “Run as Administrator” on this installation file.
3. Click through the prompts and **install a shortcut on your desktop**.
4. To run FontForge, right click on the shortcut and select “Run as Administrator.”
5. Find the font you want to edit, highlight it, and click “OK.”
6. Click Element > Font Info
7. Change the Font Name, Family Name, and Name For Humans as needed

   - Font Name should be: FamilyNameVariationName-Weight. For example: EncodeSansCondensed-ExtraBold or DMSans36pt-ExtraLight. If there is no Variation: AlegreyaSans-SemiBold.
   - Family Name should be the main name with no modifiers. For example, the Family Name of CrimsonDisplay-LightItalic, CrimsonDisplay-Black, and CrimsonText-Regular is Crimson.
   - Name for Humans should be the same as Font Name.
8. Click “Ok” after making those changes.
9. To save it, go to File > Generate Fonts.
10. Select the folder you’d like to save it to.
11. Select TrueType from the dropdown and click “Generate.”
12. You may get some errors. If you are knowledgeable about fonts and FontForge, correct them if you’d like. Otherwise, simple press “Generate” to continue.
13. The new TTF file will appear in the directory you saved it in. You may close FontForge without saving the SFD file.

Answer (score -2):

It does not appear you can do this. I opened the tahoma.ttf file in a hex editor and the version information (including the font family name) is encrypted with something from VeriSign, Inc., specifically VeriSign Time Stamping Services CA. I see the files are different versions, but I can't visually see any difference.

Comment: Difference is in the Unicode part (national fonts)

Comment: It's not encryption but _signing_: a digital signature.

Comment: It is not encypted. I have successfully edited the font.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Windows's **Font properties editor** is free and available at [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/property/fpedit.htm) (no DKIM).

It will do the job.

Comment: I couldn't change this font's name: https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts/blob/master/UbuntuMono/Ubuntu%20Mono%20derivative%20Powerline.ttf

Comment: Wow, that page https://www.microsoft.com/typography/property/fpedit.htm not edited since 2003 - felt like going back in time :S

Comment: Back in time is before 1994 (Netscape?) or 1980, or Jan 1, 1900

Comment: It redirects to a modern site now, what a shame, I wanted to see it