# Replace font with other, but keep font name

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts

I have an older Windows source code text editor which I really like to use, but I want to replace its font -- however, it does not allow picking a font via an open font dialog, and I'm restricted to a bunch of choices, like "Courier New". Is it possible to replace Courier New on my system with another font, like Doid, so that the program would then display it (thinking it's Courier New)? Thanks!

(On a sidenote, the editor is called Netpadd; I once made it in Visual Basic, but I don't have that anymore.)

Edit: Wow. Karan edited & recompiled the program Netpadd on a VM and sent it to me, it now works like a charm with custom fonts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's your own program and the [source code is available](http://www.netpadd.com/exe-based), wouldn't it be easier to install XP in a VM, obtain a copy of VB6 from somewhere and recompile the program with the necessary changes? I think this would be preferable to replacing important system fonts like Courier, Arial and Times New Roman altogether.

Comment: Thanks for this additional thought. In my case, I actually don't need Courier New specifically -- and in the cases where it's displayed by default, I'd always prefer another monospace font like Fixedsys or Doid. But recompiling the VB source is a good, cleaner suggestion. (There was a minor side problem -- last time I checked, the source did not seem to be the very latest version of the EXE, missing one or so feature I had added... but I might give it a try!)

Comment: @Philipp: Sent you mail, hope you received it.

Comment: Oh wow. You recompiled Netpadd and fixed the issue... thanks so much!!

Comment: @Philipp: Glad I could help! Was fun revisiting VB6 after ages (plus this is why open source is great, so kudos to you for sharing your code). :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/120593/change-ttf-font-name), you can rename fonts with [Typograph](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/). I have not tried it, but one of the reviews on their website specifically says it will rename fonts. It handles most font types: OpenType, TrueType and Type 1.

But I agree with Karan that it's better to leave important fonts unchanged.