# How to change name of font?

Tags: macos, fonts, otf

I want to change the PostScript name of an OTF font. I know it's possible to do this with Font Forge, but it seems like a really big deal to install this on my computer. Is there another way of doing changing the font name?

Comment: This may not be legal, as some fonts are the IP of some companies. Renaming (And then distributing at least). Just throwing it out there...

Comment: @AthomSfere It's a free font I found online. I made slight changes to its ascender properties and I want to use it inside an app alongside its original version. As they both have the same name, this isn't possible.

Comment: Does the usage policy cover redistributing it, and / or modifying it? Sometimes free means you can only use it, only use it personally. Sometimes you can do whatever you wish as long as you give credit back. And sometimes you are free to do whatever however you please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change a TTF font name?](http://superuser.com/questions/120593/how-do-you-change-a-ttf-font-name)

Comment: @davidcondrey, there is an answer there that mentions postscript, but that question asks about TTF fonts and the answers seem to focus on that.  Do you know if answers for TTF fonts are also good for postscript fonts?  I'm unfamiliar with this so don't want to vote to close as a duplicate without checking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Its actually pretty easy to do in Font Forge.  But if installing FontForge is the issue there are other, smaller, programs to the same effect.

- [TTX (requires Python)](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)

  TTX is command line and probably the easiest/smallest solution to renaming a font.  There's a brief tutorial on exactly how to do that here:  http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=343
- [Typograf](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/)
- GlyphsApp (free trial version)
- Fontographer (comparable to FontForge)