# Is it possible to alias fonts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I recently acquired some fonts that reproduce German cursive (Kurrentschrift and Sütterlin). However, they have less-than-entirely-obvious names. I can't install a font editor or other font tool to rename the actual font (organizational restrictions); is there a way that I can create an alias for a font, so that I can e.g., call for "Sütterlin" in a program (Word, etc.) and have it pick up "VolkRedis" (which is the actual font name)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Font substitution.

Font substitution is set via the registry under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`.

For example, adding an entry under this key named `Sütterlin` with the value of `VolkRedis`, indicates to substitute the Sütterlin font with the VolkRedis font.

You can do this via a `.reg` file that contains:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Sütterlin"="VolkRedis"
```

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Font-name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc939628%28v=technet.10%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: This is half of what I want; if I have an existing document that calls for Sütterlin, this will use the VolkRedis to display the Sütterlin text. It doesn't do the other half: Make available a "Sütterlin" entry in the various applications' font menus.

Comment: A wild idea is to copy the font's file in `C:\Windows\Fonts`, rename it, and also change its name in its meta-data, therefore in effect creating a new and duplicate font. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/120593/how-do-you-change-a-ttf-font-name).

Comment: Can't change the name in the metadata; that requires installing software that organizationally is disallowed. See the question again, "***I can't install a font editor or other font tool to rename the actual font (organizational restrictions); is there a way...***".

Comment: There exist online font editors. The first on Google was [FontArk](https://fontark.net/farkwp/).

Comment: Organizationally blocked, ostensibly category "Games". This sort of thing is why I'm looking for a way to alias the font, rather than simply renaming it.

Comment: It seems like you will need to do that from some other computer, or in a virtual machine.

Comment: In other words, the only option is to rename the font, rather than aliasing it?

Comment: Yes, but renaming the file is not enough. The metadata also needs to be modified, since Windows goes by the metadata and not by the file-name. Otherwise, aliasing is the only solution.

Comment: _Aliasing_ is what I'm trying to do, but your solution seems to be to _rename_ the font - and I do understand the difference between renaming the _font_ vs. renaming the _font file_. Are you in fact telling me that my only option is to rename the font? Or is there a way to alias it such that the alias will show up in the font list for e.g., a new document in Word.

Comment: The font characteristics are contained *inside* the font file, which includes its name, family, sizes etc. When searching/using fonts this is the data that is accessed in the Windows font database. The font *file-name* itself is of no importance. That means that for really renaming a font, you need a font editor. Aliasing/substituting is simpler, just creating equivalents (and if you notice uses the font-name and not the file-name).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. _That is precisely what I am asking how to do._ The font substitution table only does _half_ the job; I'm looking for the other half as well.

Comment: For the other half (actually an alternative), you will need to edit the font. These two are the only solutions.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin, to make available a "Sütterlin" entry in the various applications' font menus, install a font named "Sütterlin" in your system.  Then the substitution described in this answer will do its job.

Comment: @balazer - that's part of the problem. I have a font that _is_ an implementation of Sütterlin script, but it's not called that, and I haven't found one that is.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I don't believe the aliasing you want exists in Windows.  You can use a font editing tool on a different machine to rename the font and then copy it over.